# Access denied while checking MySQL version

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-16.04, mysql-5.6

I installed MySQL5.6 on Ubuntu 16.04.

I am trying to get MySQL version by using command

> mysql -v

getting this error "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)"

Please assist

Comment: Try sudo mysql -V
with capital 'V'

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the version:

```
mysql --version
```

The `-v` option is the *verbose flag*, not version, meaning it tries to connect to the server. In order to do that you need valid credentials.

For more information:

```
mysql --help
```